# Can I set up automated publication of a Magento CMS page?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, cron, schedule

is there a way to schedule publication of a Magento CMS page that is under version control?

ie:

On March 3, 2011 at 12:00am, change CMS page 'Home Page' from Verision A to Version B

is there anything built into Magento that would handle that? or would I need to DIY?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to DIY this, although it's a pretty clear path forward.

1. Setup a [Magento Cron Job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) event listener
2. Have that listener manipulate `cms/page` models to achieve your end goals

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin -> CMS -> Home -> Custom design

Then set Custom Design From and Custom Design To as you want.
You need to have [Magento Cron Job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) configured in your server.

Comment: I thaught that too, but you can't specify the home page through design, it's a system-config field